# enabling Xdebug on windows 7 XAMMP 1.7.4

Tags: php, zend-framework, xdebug

I am using Windows 7 and XAMMP 1.7.4. I am confused on how to enable Xdebug. Googling suggested to download xDebug dll , but there are different version of dll on Xdebug site , which confusing me.

Moreover there is Zend debugging and then there Xdebug which one to use ??

How can i enable debugging in Xdebug.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow this tutorial on getting started with xdebug : http://devzone.zend.com/article/2803-Introducing-xdebug

Xdebug and ZendDebug are two separate debuggers, it's up to you to decide which one to use. Either one is pretty easy to setup. Only a couple of steps in Eclipse.

Post the content from your php info page into this page to find out which version to download : http://www.xdebug.org/find-binary.php

Just match your PHP version and OS version. Windows is generally the *VC6 version